The problem of moving a variable to another page
Hi I’m using this code in my page to move to the same page but with account access, I’m learning how to use various languages so I didn’t want to use Javascript.
<label for="toggleBanner" class="open-btn">Log In</label>

      <!-- Overlay del banner -->
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <!-- Etichetta per chiudere il banner -->
          <label for="toggleBanner" class="close">&times;</label>
          <h2>Inserisci credenziali</h2>
          <form method="post" action="LogIn.php?CODICE=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($codice, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
            <label for="name">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>
            
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
            
            <input type="submit" value="Invia">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

The problem that occurs is that the $codice that passes from one page to another is not received and is always interpreted 0.
Thanks in advance for any advice, and also for tips on other things
Despite having checked several times that before pressing send the page knows which code it refers to.

Include the code where you receive the variable, also if you have done any debugging tell us, if not just print_r($_GET) in the page you are receiving the code to see if it's there

You need to learn to differentiate between variable names, and parameter names. The variable you used to output the value inside the form action there, was named $codice, yes. But you named the URL parameter CODICE, and since it is submitted via the URL, you need to access it via $_GET - so $_GET['CODICE'] is what you are looking for in the script that processes this form submission.

Agreed, you didn't show us how you are accessing this variable again the LogIn.php script so we can't check if you've done that correctly or not (if you have, then the only other explanation is that $codice was already 0 when you echoed it into your login form - but your last paragraph seems to rule that out). However...the method of passing variables from one page to another, and how it's done in web applications, and how specifically that works in PHP, is extremely well-documented online already - are you sure you really need to ask a new question about that?
